# Change URL Structure in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have a menu structure like this

```
1 About_us
1.1 Physicians
1.2 Locations
```

So when a user selects Physicians, url will be www.abc.com/about_us/physicians.html

I want to change it to www.abc.com/physicians.html

Any Help?

Comment: what SEF component are you using?

Comment: we are not using any SEF component. We have enabled the SEF url in joomla config only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hidden menu with a position called physicians and link to it from the second-level items of your main menu.